# Change of Variables of Exponential Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $U,V$ be independent random variables with exponential $1$ distribution. We further consider $X_1 = U, X_2 = \frac{U}{U+V}$ and $X_3 = U + V$. We want to show that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent, but that $\mathbb{E}[X_3 \space | \space \sigma(X_1, X_2)] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_3 \space | \space \sigma(X_1)]$.

For the first part, I think we need to use the change of variables formula, while for the second one I suppose we have to compute both sides separately, but I am not sure how to proceed.

---

For the independence, we can consider the change of
given by $\frac{x=u}{u+v}$ and $y=u+v$. We can then invert the change and compute the Jacobian, which is $y$. Then we apply the change of variables formula to get the joint pdf of $X_2$ and $_3$; this is $e^{-y}y$, so the variables are independent with $_2$
being Uniform in $[0,1]$ and $_3$ being Gamma with parameters $2,1$. However, I am having trouble computing the expectations, since I have no clear idea what to do when the conditions are $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: I am sure you can compute at least one of the conditional expectations if you try. Also, you should search the site for the first part.

Comment: Please show your detailed attempts to answer before we can provide more help.

Comment: For the independence, we can consider the change of variables $(u, v) \to (x,y)$ given by $x=\frac{u}{u+v}$ and $y=u+v$. We can then invert the change and compute the Jacobian, which is $y$. Then we apply the change of variables formula to get the joint pdf of $X_2$ and $X_3$. This is $e^{-y}y$, so the variables are independent with $X_2$ being Uniform on $[0, 1]$ and $X_3$ being Gamma with parameters $2, 1$. However, I am having trouble computing the expectations, since I have no clear idea what to do when the conditions are $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Hint: $X_3$ is a function of both, $X_1$ and $X_2$. What is then $\mathbb E[X_3|\sigma(X_1,X_2)]$ ?